# Return a list of missing values?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The following line produces a list of existing datapoints:

```
datapoint_list = organisation.datapoint_set.filter(timestamp__gte=startDate, timestamp__lte=endDate)
```

I would like to `return` in JSON format the dates from `startDate` to `lastDate` for which there is no existing datapoint.

How can this be done?

My best idea is to:

```
class Missing(generics.ListAPIView)
    ...
    queryset = organisation.datapoint_set.filter(timestamp__gte=startDate, timestamp__lte=endDate)

    Loop over the datesdelta
        Loop over the datapoints
            If datapoint.timestamp == datedelta.timestamp then
                Push timestamp to object
                Continue
            End if
        End loop
    End loop
    Return object
```

But I haven't succeeded in looping of the dates. And maybe there is even a simpler way to do this?

**EDIT:**

The datesdelta is determined from query params and should by default look for missing datapoints in the last week:

```
    days = int(self.request.query_params.get('days', 7))
    startDate = datetime.today() - timedelta(days)
    endDate = datetime.today()
```

The queryset contains:

```
<DataPoint: Value: 123, Timestamp: 2015-12-15>
<DataPoint: Value: 123, Timestamp: 2015-12-11>
<DataPoint: Value: 123, Timestamp: 2015-12-10>
<DataPoint: Value: 123, Timestamp: 2015-12-09>
<DataPoint: Value: 123, Timestamp: 2015-12-08>
```

The JSON output should look something like

```
[
    'date': '2015-12-16',
    'date': '2015-12-14',
    'date': '2015-12-13',
    'date': '2015-12-12',
    'date': '2015-11-07'
}
```

My question is how to get from that queryset to that output.

Comment: Can you give more details please, such as the datesdela list content and how it looks the output you want?

Comment: Thank for taking interest in the question @DhiaTN! I have added more details in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set()` Learn to use that and you'll rule the world! First, a slight modification to your query, based on the example you're showing you ONLY want the dates so lets make the query more efficient:

```
queryset = organisation.datapoint_set.filter(timestamp__gte=startDate, timestamp__lte=endDate).values_list('timestamp', flat=True)
```

done, this will look something like this:

```
queryset = [datetime(2015,12,15), datetime(2015,12,11), datetime(2015,12,10), datetime(2015,12,9), datetime(2015,12,8)]
```

Now we generate the values we want:

```
>>> set([endDate - timedelta(x) for x in xrange(days)])
set([datetime.date(2015, 12, 14), datetime.date(2015, 12, 16), datetime.date(2015, 12, 15), datetime.date(2015, 12, 12), datetime.date(2015, 12, 13), datetime.date(2015, 12, 10), datetime.date(2015, 12, 11)])
```

Perfect, and we (subtract them) `-`:

```
>>> set([endDate - timedelta(x) for x in xrange(days)]) - set(queryset)
set([datetime.date(2015, 12, 14), datetime.date(2015, 12, 16), datetime.date(2015, 12, 15), datetime.date(2015, 12, 12), datetime.date(2015, 12, 13), datetime.date(2015, 12, 10), datetime.date(2015, 12, 11)])
```

Lets make it all pretty:

```
import datetime
days = 10
# a bit of a hack to get the current date without any time stuff.
endDate = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.datetime.min.time())
queryset = [datetime.datetime(2015,12,15), datetime.datetime(2015,12,11), datetime.datetime(2015,12,10), datetime.datetime(2015,12,9), datetime.datetime(2015,12,8)]
date_ranges = set([endDate - datetime.timedelta(x) for x in xrange(days)])
output = sorted(list(date_ranges - set(queryset)))
print([x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in output])
```

output is:

```
['2015-12-07', '2015-12-12', '2015-12-13', '2015-12-14', '2015-12-16']
```

if you timestamps come as `date` objects its even easier:

```
import datetime
days = 10
endDate = datetime.date.today()
queryset = [datetime.date(2015,12,15), datetime.date(2015,12,11), datetime.date(2015,12,10), datetime.date(2015,12,9), datetime.date(2015,12,8)]
date_ranges = set([endDate - datetime.timedelta(x) for x in xrange(days)])
output = sorted(list(date_ranges - set(queryset)))
print([x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in output])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the timestamps from the query using [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list). To get only the distinct values in the result you can combine `values_list` with [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

```
timestamps = organisation.datapoint_set.filter(timestamp__gte=today-timedelta(days), timestamp__lte=today).values_list('timestamp',flat=True)
```

So now `timestamps` list has all the timestamps on which there is some data point. You may want o convert them to string objects first.

```
ts = [str(t) for t in timestamps]
```

Now loop over the days from `today` to `today-days`

```
ts_list = []
for day in xrange(days+1):
    dat = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=-day)
    if str(dat) not in ts:
        print dat
        ts_list.append(dat)
```

This will give all dates which does not have data points

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follow:

```
class MissingListApiView(generics.ListAPIView)
    model = Organisation
    serializer_class = OrganisationSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

       datapoint_list = organisation.datapoint_set.filter(timestamp__gte=today-timedelta(days), timestamp__lte=today)
       get_timestap = lambda x: x.timestamp
       timestamp_list = map(get_timestap, datapoint_list)
       response = list()
       push = response.append
       for day in xrange(days+1):
          date = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=-day)
          if str(dat) not in timestamp_list:
             push(datapoint.timestamp)
       Return response
```